# CSS Accodion Menu not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, cross-browser

I need to create a simple accordion style menu that displays/hides when clicked. It works in IE11 and FF but does not close in Chrome/Safari. Can anyone provide a work around for these browsers? I like the simpleness of this code and would like to use it if possible.. Thanks!

```css
.show{
  display:none;
}
.hide:focus+.show{
  display:inline;
}
.hide:focus{
  display:none;
}
.hide:focus~#list{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>Accordian Example</p>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="hide">[hide]</a>
    <a href="#" class="show">[show]</a>
    <ol id="list">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked that on FF and Chrome.

**Reason for different behaviour**

In Chrome, when an element has its `display` property set to `none`, it can not be in focused state, which I believe is a more predictable and uniform behavior. But In Firefox, even when the element has its `display` property set to `none` it is some how retaining the focus.

Now, since both the browsers are behaving differently with focus retention of the element, the net output of your code is different browser.

**Can you use this approach ? : NO ... the reason is :**

Even if you consider the Firefox, since your visibility of the accordion content is based on the focus, as soon as the user click anywhere on the site, even on the blank portion of the site, the element will loose its focus, and it won't work as expected.

To verify this, open that example on firefox, click on hide, then click on white space, you will see that the list items will re-appear.

**A better approach for CSS only accordion**

This uses a checkbox to decide when to show or hide. We hide the checkbox, by placing it outside of the viewport and using a label to create a clickable area.

```css
#toggler{
position:fixed;
  top:-100px;
}
label{
cursor:pointer;
}
#toggler ~ ol{
  display:none;
}
#toggler:checked ~ ol{
  display:block;
}

#toggler ~ label .show,#toggler:checked ~ label .hide{
  display:inline-block;
}
#toggler:checked ~ label .show,#toggler ~ label .hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>Accordian Example</p>
<div>
  <input id="toggler" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label for="toggler">
      Toggle Accordion
      <b class="show">[show]</b>
      <b class="hide">[hide]</b>
      
    </label>
    <ol id="list">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response on this! I will try it on our server and let you now how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try This
```

```css
.show { display:none;}
.hide , .show { position :absolute; top:0; left:0; }
 .hide:focus {opacity:0; font-size:0;}
 .hide:focus + .show { display:block;}
 .hide:focus~.list {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#" class="hide"><span>[hide]<span></a>
<a href="#" class="show">[show]</a>
<ol class="list">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response I will try this example as well!

Comment: @Neileo72  Run this example, Click on hide to hide, and then click anywhere else, the list items will reappear, because as you click somewhere else, the .hide will loose its focus, hence consider avoiding the use of focus for accordians, as they generally have  multiple sets each having show/hide content, so if you use :focus, so once you focus somewhere else, all sets will reappear